# Angular5 keep lazy-loading but not add intermediate level in url

Tags: angular, routes, lazy-loading

I have Angular5 app with users. I use lazy-loading so that the url of user's page  is like http://example.com/user/:name. But I want to change the url to http://example.com/:name. Is there any solution to realise it with keeping lazy-loading ?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly this is not possible.

Imagine the following scenario. You define your routes for your app.module like this:

```
const routes: Routes[] = [{
      path: '',
      component: HomeComponent
   }, {
      path: ':someIdentifier1',
      loadChildren: 'app/somesubpath1/somemodule1#SomeModule1
   }, {
      path: ':someIdentifier2',
      loadChildren: 'app/somesubpath2/somemodule2#SomeModule2'
   }
]
```

The router cannot distingush between a router-link that leads to /somesubpath1/abcd and a router-link that leads to /somesubpath2/abcd and therefore it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a workaround, a wrapper module that then lazily loads your route.  Something like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '**',
        component: WrapperComponent,
        children: [{
            path: ':user',
            loadChildren: 'user-module#UserModule',
        }]
      },
    ])
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class WrapperRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my app, I do exactly what you are requesting, however I am not using lazy loading. It seems to work just fine for me, I don't see why lazy loading would make a difference as the router path matching should be the same across the board. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong!

What I do is make sure I include the modules with a hard path up at the top, and I put the catch-all route module at the very bottom. This way, the ones that are found will be loaded and everything else will load the catch-all route.

For instance, here is my `AppModule`:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        // ...

        HomeModule,
        // other page modules here...

        // UserModule should always go last since it has a catchall URL path in its routes
        // to find user by username, for example /@Lansana.
        UserModule
    ],
    providers: [...],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

As you can see, the `UserModule` is listed last because it is the one with the catch-all route.

I imagine you could take the same approach with your lazy loading. Give that a shot.